# Formatting a row according to specific criteria in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, rows

My workbook presents a table with a date in the last column (J) in the format "Tuesday, June 30, 2020" etc. Is there a way to search each cell in that column and highlight that entire row in a specific colour according to the day of the week? The code I have works if the day of the week is isolated but not when it is part of a date string. It highlights a single cell but I want it to highlight the whole row. I want it to apply to each sheet in the workbook apart from the sheet named "AllData"

```
Sub FormatUsingVBA()
Dim rng As range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As range
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = range("J2:J" & lastRow)
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value Like "Sunday" Then
range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You're asking for a VBA solution? you could use Conditional Formatting

Comment: Yes the table would be much easier to read if, for example, I could add vba code to pick out 'Sunday' and make that row green. I'm quite new to VBA and just finding my way around

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some code so we can help you with something in particular

Answer (score 0):

Yes

- Select for example column A to D
- Select menu: Home/Conditional formatting
- New Rule
- "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format"
- Put formula: =$D1="Sunday
  and link a formattign to it (for example green background)
  (supposing that in Column D you have "Sunday")

Apply and all rows with value Sunday in column D will be in green.